# Finding prime numbers using lists in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, list, numbers, compare, primes

I'm trying to make a program that finds prime numbers using lists in Python 3.3.2. What I'm trying to do is take ONE element from `ns` and divide it by ALL of the elements from `b`.

This is what I've got (doesn't work):

```
b = [1]
ns = [1]

while 1 == 1:
    if ns[-1] / b[:] == 1 or ns[-1]:
        print (ns[-1])
        ns.append(ns[-1]+1)
        b.append(b[-1]+1)
    else:
        print ("No prime found.")
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
if ns[-1] / b[:] == 1 or ns[-1]:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

I understand why this operation is impossible (dividing an integer element from a list by another entire list just doesn't work) and was wondering if there was any way to achieve my goal.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you come any further, did my answer help?

Comment: Not quite. I'm not very experienced in python (or any sort of coding language). Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide an integer and a list. What you could do is use a list comprehension. Demo:

```
>>> ns = [1,2,3]
>>> b= [7,9,12,13]
>>> # divide last element of ns by all elements of b
... 
>>> [float(ns[-1])/item for item in b if item]
[0.42857142857142855, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.23076923076923078]
```

The first element of the new list is 3/7 the second element is 3/9, and so on. The `if item` check is there to ensure that you don't divide by zero.

edit: You could actually mean something different, that is dividing one element from `ns` by every element in `b` in succession. Demo for `ns[-1]`:

```
>>> ns = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> sol = ns[-1]
>>> for item in b:
...     sol = float(sol)/item
... 
>>> sol
0.5
```

sol is ((3/3)/2)/1

Also, your `while` loop is never going to end. Are you sure you want that?